# When I run the code, it runs without errors, but the csv file is not created, why?

Tags: python

I found a tutorial and I'm trying to run this script, I did not work with python before.
[tutorial](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/spy-on-competitors-python-data-studio/306841/amp/)

I've already seen what is running through logging.debug, checking whether it is connecting to google and trying to create csv file with other scripts

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs

from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get
import csv
def scrape_run():
    with open('/Users/Work/Desktop/searches.txt') as searches:
        for search in searches:
           userQuery = search
           raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + userQuery).text
           page = fromstring(raw)
           links = page.cssselect('.r a')

           csvfile = '/Users/Work/Desktop/data.csv'
           for row in links:
               raw_url = row.get('href')
               title = row.text_content()
               if raw_url.startswith("/url?"):
                   url = parse_qs(urlparse(raw_url).query)['q']
                   csvRow = [userQuery, url[0], title]
                   with open(csvfile, 'a') as data:
                       writer = csv.writer(data)
                       writer.writerow(csvRow)
                       print(links)

scrape_run()
```

The TL;DR of this script is that it does three basic functions:

- Locates and opens your searches.txt file.
- Uses those keywords and    searches the first page of Google for each
  result.
- Creates a new CSV    file and prints the results (Keyword, URLs, and
  page titles).

Comment: `print` debugging is best debugging. does `print(links)` prints anything? if it does add a `print(csvRow)`

Comment: While you do open de file in append mode, you may be better off opening the file *before* your (outer?) for-loop, so that you only have to open it once. And create the writer also at that stage, instead of creating a new writer each step of the loop.

Comment: print(links) empty,  i think its a problem, but why its empty

Comment: Google uses JavaScript to display data. But requests can't run JavaScript and you get different HTML then you expect. Open web browser, turn off JavaScript and run Google search - you will see what `requests` can see. OR you have to use Selenium to control web browser which will run JavaScript.

Comment: @furas google search page uses server side rendering, i have tested it, parsing the response should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `links` variable is full and contains data - please verify.
if empty - test the api call itself you are making, maybe it returns something different than you expected.

Other than that - I think you just need to tweak a little bit your file handling.

https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html
here you can find some guidelines regarding file handling in python.
in my perspective, you need to make sure you create the file first. 
start on with a script which is able to just create a file.
after that enhance the script to be able to write and append to the file.
from there on I think you are good to go and continue with you're script.
other than that I think that you would prefer opening the file only once instead of each loop, it could mean much faster execution time.

let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Google add captcha couse i use to many request
its work when i use mobile internet